# Is there data available on physical goods and services traded in BTC?

Tags: trading

There seems to be plenty of data on the BTC financial market, exchange rates and the like, as well as on the technical aspects (network hash rate, difficulty etc).

I guess I'm not the only one interested in what amount of BTC is spent on actual goods and services, but all I can find is the occasional number by some specific trading platform, for some specific timeframe, nothing more systematic.

Comment: there are a couple companies that are known to pay employees in btc, and you can check auctions on various bitcoin forums. this will help you do your independent research

Comment: I'm sure [bitcoin store](https://www.bitcoinstore.com/) has this data, though I'm not sure if they would share it. Perhaps you can glean some from their site though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know this with a 100% accuracy. Because when you look from outside, a trader moving Bitcoins between exchanges is no different from someone paying for a services/goods with Bitcoins. Both are Bitcoin transactions. The same goes for people moving money internationally, sending their parents Bitcoins, a company paying it's employees etc. You really can't separate these from purchases of actual goods and services. Because like I said, they're all transactions.

However, if you want to measure speculative interest in Bitcoin vs. interest in Bitcoin as a currency(i.e for practical things) then you can look at this graph:

http://blockchain.info/charts/tx-trade-ratio

And the discussion about it:

http://codinginmysleep.com/measuring-bitcoin-speculation/

Both the discussion and the data is quite far from conclusive though.